# Copy Data and increment PK in destination table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a temp table with data that needs to be split into 3 other tables. Each of those tables has a primary key that is not shared with each other or with the temp table. Here is a small sampling:

Table 1

```
RSN     AGENT   STATUS  STATUS DECRIPTION
0   280151  51  Terminated
1   86  57  C/O Comp Agent Dele
2   94  57  C/O Comp Agent Dele
3   108 51  Terminated
```

Table 2

```
RSN     AGENT   CITY
1   10  Englewood
2   123 Jackson
3   35  Eatontown
4   86  Trenton
```

Table 3

```
RSN     AGT     SIGN    NO_EMP  START_DATE
0   241008  Y   1   2002-10-31 00:00:00.000
1   86  Y   0   2002-10-24 09:51:10.247
2   94  Y   0   2002-10-24 09:51:10.247
3   108 Y   0   2002-10-24 09:51:10.247
```

I need to check each table to see if the data in the temp table exists and if it does not I want to insert those rows with a RSN# starting with the max number in that table. So if I have 5000 records in the first table and I am adding 5000 new rows they will be numbered 5001 through 10000.

I then need to check to see if any columns have changed for matching rows and update them.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Scott

Comment: Why are you not using identity fields for your ids?

Comment: are you using one temp table for all 3 tables? what is the structure of your temp table?

Comment: @HLGEM - I didn't construct this database. I just have to live with it the way it is. The Agent is also a unique identifier in all 3 tables, so why that is not the PK is unknown to me.

Comment: @Bulat - I am using a single temp table. The file that it was imported from is 77 columns and a mix of numeric and varchar. The table has more than the 77 columns now because I have had to create some other columns for concatenating values. There are columns in at least one of the final tables that are based off of values in other columns of the import file as well.

Comment: @HLGEM - I can add an identity column to my temp table and populate it before the copy. I am just not sure how to get the max value from the destination table and add 1 to it as the seed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding 4 new columns to my staging table; a temp rsn#, which is an identity column starting with 1, and an rsn# for each of my 3 destination tables. I created a variable getting the max value from each table and then added that to my temp rsn#.

Comment: There are some issues in this that should have been obvious to me and probably were to anyone else who read this. Even though this worked correctly to update my new columns with sequential numbers only some of those rows are being added to tables. So if the last number in my destination table is 5260 the new table may be numbered from 5261 and up but maybe only number 7121, 8150 and 8765 are being added so the destination is no longer in sequential order.

Answer (score 0):

You have to repeat the code bellow for T1, 2 and 3 and update matching and not matching columns.

Insert new value:

```
Insert Into Table1(col1, col2, ...)
Select t.col1, t.col2
From temp as t 
Left Join table1 as t1 On t.matchcol1 = t1.matchcol1 and t.matchcol2 = t1.matchcol2
Where t.col1 is null
```

replace matchcol1 by a list of matching columns between T and T1

update:

```
Update t1 set col1 = t.col1, t.col2 = t1.col2, ...
From table1 as t1
Inner Join temp as t On t.matchcol1 = t1.matchcol1 and t.matchcol2 = t1.matchcol2 and ...
Where col1 <> t.col1 or t.col2 <> t1.col2 or ...
```

This may work as well:

I am not sure you really need to update something or just insert and how you link temp and table1 in order to know if it has been changed.

```
Insert Into Table1(RSN, AGENT, STATUS, STATUS, DECRIPTION)
Select (Select max(RSN) From table1) + Row_number() over(order by agent)
     , AGENT, STATUS, STATUS, DECRIPTION
From (
   Select AGENT, STATUS, STATUS, DECRIPTION From TempTable
   Except
   Select AGENT, STATUS, STATUS, DECRIPTION From Table1
) as t1
```

Or you can upgrade to SQL Server 2008 and use Merge. It would be a lot easier